# Cite right and layout bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have two problems with the citiation and the appendent reference inside the bibliography.

The citiation should look like that

```
(Author, 2012, S. 3)
```

but with the styles i found it woun't be formatted like that.

And the reference should look like that:

```
For books: 
Author, (1987c). Title. publisher.

For website references:
Name, V. (year, day/month of publication). page title. accessed on:  date.
Link: website.
```

I created a bib file at the beginning of my assay and most of my references are websites and look like this:

```
@online{blackberry,
    author = {Blackberry},
    title = {BlackBerry Smart Card Reader},
    year = {2012},
    url = {http://uk.blackberry.com/ataglance/security/products/smartcardreader/},
    OPTnote = {https://www.evernote.com/shard/s206/sh/055c5f0f-fb82-4197-a733-5b48c91f5f1b/71e1a2ed70610cd308e6aa6609023e73},
    OPTdate = {20.09.2012},
}
```

I read, there can be created a new bibliographystyle, but therefore i would need to learn a new syntax. Is there another possibility to do that. If not, is there a manually way to get this work?

Comment: Do you use any bibliography manager style (e.g. `natbib`) and what is the BibTeX style you use?

Comment: I use the package \usepackage{bibgerm}, \bibliographystyle{acm}. but didn't read about a bibliography manager. Is the manager able to layout everything?

Comment: If you use BibLaTeX, then it can take care of everything. Knowing the bib manager could be useful when one modifies a `.bst`. Are you restricted to BibTeX or you can consider BibLaTeX?

Comment: I have never modified a .bst-file. I still have problems with tex inside the assay. There, if possible I would just do everything manually at the end of my assay. But if a manager can solve this problem, i would look for this....

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with BibDesk. But when i want to generate the Cite Key.... it doesn't allow comma, space or the pagenumber.... is there one somebody can recommend? I found a list on Wikipedia but would be glad if somebody can give me an advise

Comment: BibDesk is a program to interface/manage a BibTeX database, it has nothing to do on how the reference will be printed in the output produced by TeX/LaTeX. Have you tried with the provided answer? (adding the comma after the year  in the bibliography is rather simple)

Comment: I just tried to change the way the cite key appears. But i didn't try to solve the problem with the workaround inside the bibliography. will try this to. But i thought the provided answer was, to use a bib manager... like bib desk. 
But is there another way instead of the ".bst" file how to solve the citiation formatting problem?

Answer (score 2):

You ask quite a two separate questions. Regarding your first question, how to generate a citation of the form

```
(Author, 2012, S. 3)
```

I recommend you (i) load the `natbib` package:

```
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
```

and (ii) use the natbib package's `\citep` (short for "parenthetical" citation style) as follows (assuming the reference's key is "author:2012"):

```
\citep[S.~3]{author:2012}
```

Regarding the formatting of the items in the References section: You appear to have some idiosyncratic formatting requirements, only some of which are spelled out in your posting. I recommend you run the `makebst` utility (by the same person who authored the `natbib` package) to create a *custom* bibliography style (`.bst`) file that incorporates all of your requirements. At a command prompt, type `latex makebst` and follow the detailed, menu-style prompts. The program will ask you lots of questions and provide possible answers; at the end, type "y" when asked if you want to create the `.bst` file. Be sure to move the new `.bst` file to a location where it can be found by the TeX distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using BibLaTeX,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
  natbib,
  firstinits=true,
  % backend=bibtex,  % uncomment this line to use BibTeX as backend
  language=american]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents} % to make the example self contained
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @online{blackberry,
      author = {Blackberry},
      title = {BlackBerry Smart Card Reader},
      date = {2012-09-01},
      url = {http://uk.blackberry.com/ataglance/security/products/smartcardreader/},
      urldate = {2012-09},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{
  url = {Link},
  urlseen = {Accessed on},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibcpstring{url}: \url{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{date}{%
  \thefield{year}%
  \iffieldundef{month}
    {}
    {\addspace\iffieldundef{day}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{month}}}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{day}}}/\stripzeros{\thefield{month}}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{
  \bibcpstring{urlseen}
  \setunit{\addcolon\addspace} 
  \iffieldundef{urlday}
    {}
    {\printfield{urlday}\setunit{/}}%
  \iffieldundef{urlmonth}
    {}
    {\printfield{urlmonth}\setunit{/}}%
  \printfield{urlyear}
}  

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printurldate
  \newunit
  \printfield{url}
}


\begin{document}
\citep[S.~3]{blackberry}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]